Child object drives Parent object movement, Child object behaves weirdly
I make a control sphere parented under a camera, the control sphere drives a target cube's location.
Camera needs to follow the target cube when it moves, so the camera is parented under the cube.
Now the control sphere is moving quite fast and weird ?
Here's what I record :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afq6DbcV3uc
First half camera not parented under cube, looks fine
Second half when parented, when I move sphere a little bit, it goes far away
How can I solve this ???


Maybe there's a circular dependency, if the sphere is child of the camera, and the cube is drived by the sphere, I guess you can't make the camera follow the cube, as the cube is kind of child of its child?

That's definitely circular dependency. A child follows the movement of its parent, you have a clear hierarchy there: moving the cube moves the camera and this moves the sphere. However changing the sphere's location drives the cube's location which in turn again affects camera and sphere, like a dog chasing its own tail. I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but first I would break up this hierarchy. It's nod a good idea to have the "grandchild" control the "grandparent".

There's a circular dependency problem, you can't make a parent obey to its child's child. Maybe describe what is your project exactly so that we propose an alternative solution.

Thanks, let me elaborate :
I'm making a mini car game.
I need a UI to control the car.
Now I'm using the sphere movement to drive the parameter for steering the car
.But as you see the problem above.
I think I need screen space UI or something ?
